# Search for jsonb concatenated values specified by keys

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, jsonb

I have jsonb data as :

```
id | data
1  | {"last": "smith", "first": "john", "title": "mr"}
2  | {"last": "smith jr", "first": "john", "title": "mr"}
3  | {"last": "roberts", "first": "Julia", "title": "miss"}
4  | {"last": "2nd", "first": "john smith", "title": "miss"}
```

I need to search for records which match with "John smith"; So, in this case IDs - 1,2,4
I cannot separate the search for each key => value pair; I need to get concatenated entry for records to check against incoming request.

I have tried

```
select * from contacts where jsonb_concat(data->>'title'::TEXT || data->>'first'::TEXT || data->>'last'::TEXT) ilike "John smith";
```

This doesn't work because I am trying to concat values and not jsonb object. Is there any way to concat jsonb values specified by keys?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with some research..
my query is like -

```
 select * from contacts where trim(regexp_replace(CONCAT(data->>'title'::TEXT,' ',data->>'first'::TEXT,' ',data->>'last'::TEXT), '\s+', ' ', 'g')) ilike '%john%';
```

For PostgreSQL versions > 9.1 .. you can use '\s+' instead of '\s+'.

hope this helps someone.